# Docker Image works in docker-compose but not with docker[React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Hello I am making this post because I have only been able to find people with the opposite issue of the image working in docker but not with docker-compose.

I am working on a full-stack application utilizing React, Node, and Mongo.
Here is my set up

Running `docker-compose up` works and has the expected results. Everything connects and runs fine.

However I wanted to be able to run each image in isolation to perform testing.

Building the React Dockerfile with `docker build -t <name>` followed by `docker run <name>` starts the image, dependecies get loaded but then the application hangs. It is unable to be canceled via terminal using ctrl+c, and can only be closed by deleting it from the docker desktop app (or maybe running in detached and killing somewhere else). Either way it does not work.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  react:
    build: ./re_react
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000
  node: #node service
    build: ./node #check for the node folder containing our docker file 
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    environment: #env vars 
      MONGO_URL: mongodb://db-mongo:27017
    depends_on:
      db-mongo:
        condition: service_started
  db-mongo: #MongoDB Service
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes: #volume 
      - mongo_store:/data/db
    healthcheck: #healthcheck also very unsure if its working
      test: ["CMD", "/etc/init.d/mongodb", "status"]
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
volumes:
  mongo_store:
```

**Node: Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /server/src
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

**React: Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /react/

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY  public/ ./public
COPY src/ ./src

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I have tried moving some of the commands around in the **React:Dockerfile** to no avail, and I am considering it could be a port issue?

I'm totally unclear and lost on what the problem could be.

Also the node image runs fine (albiet it depends on an environment variable from the compose so it does generate an error after running, but it does not hang).

[Output from `docker build -t <name>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyjNd.png)

The build seems to go without issue

[Running with `docker run <name`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu8G1.png)
Program is dead in the water at this stage and nolonger recieving any inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the actual command, but you have to run the container along with [publishing port](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish) to the host machine. Same is applicable for the Node.js project as well (backend).

```bash
docker run --publish 3000:3000
```

However, this *Dockerfile* is **NOT** for production. For that, you have to build the app and serve it through a web server.

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /react
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./src .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /react/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed it. I figured it would probably be some port issue because my compose file was handling the port binding and I wasn't doing that anywhere when I was just running docker.

Answer (score -1):

Try this both for frontend and backend

build:
context: #path of backend or frontend project
dockerfile: Dockerfile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).